# Making the final product of one function play off the final product of a different function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to write a code where it randomly generates numbers and can then subtract those numbers for a solution. If I had a code like this:

```
def rand1():
    rand1 = random.choice('123456789')
    print rand1

def rand2():
    rand2 = random.choice('987654321')
    print rand2
```

Is there a way I could do `rand1() - rand2()`? Or any suggestions on how I could make them play off one another. Thanks

Comment: Your functions are not returning anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having `print`, if you do `return` you can do that. You also need to convert the `str` to an `int` using `int()`.

Your methods should look like this instead

```
def rand1():
        rand1 = random.choice('123456789')
        return int(rand1)
def rand2():
        rand2 = random.choice('987654321')
        return int(rand2)
```

Comment: Super helpful, simple little fix I didn't think about, thanks!

Comment: @EthanPerrin , allow me to stress the difference between print and return, in Python 2... `print` simply *prints* out what it's given, no further computation or interaction is really possible with such output. However, `return` actually *returns* an object that you can manipulate and compute further by - for example - assigning to a variable or feeding into another function or method.